# How to deal with large arrays?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm dealing with a problem here. I have 600.000 words extracted from a book, what I need to do is to put these words in a database. The thing is, I collect these words the first time I open the said book. What I'm doing is using an async task to read all words, the problem: where do I put these words before I insert them into the database ? I tried with ArrayList, array and also tried to concatenate them into a single giant String. But always face the same problem, out of memory.

Should I try to insert the words directly into the database? Should I try store into smaller ArrayLists, insert, clear the ArrayList and start from where I stopped? I'm out of ideas. Thanks.

Below, my asynctask:

```
private class storeWords extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {        

        JTPagina drmPage = new JTPagina();
        JTObra dadosObra = new JTObra();

        int res = access.getPage(idBook, currentPage, drmPage);

        JTPalavra[] palavras;
        palavras = drmPage.getPalavras();

        //Log.d("--->", "" + currentPage);


        if (currentPage + 1 < pageCount) {
            for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
                list.add(palavras[i].getPalavra());
            }


            try {
                MoveNext(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I would try directly to DB as well, that has virtually 0 memory usage.

Comment: I would have implemented something like lazy/paginating word reader, wich holds only fixed bunch of data at the time and transparently retrieve it only on demand.

Comment: don't put them anywhere, just store them directly into database

Comment: You cannot hold all your data in memory, different container decisions cannot help you. Read some amount of data (like 100 or 1000, choose it by yourself) and store them to database, repeat until all data is stored. Inserting to database one by one is slow

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What I did was: get all words from one page, add them into the ArrayList and after that insert into the database, move to the next page and so on.